# How to populate a different View on redirect and trigger button submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC/ASP.NET

I have two views, one displays a list of items based on a group ID. the other page displays various pieces of information which is generated from multiple options. which options the user can enter are determined from a dropdown select.

**View1.aspx**

```
<input type="button" 
       value="View All Details%>" 
       class="button" 
       onclick="window.location = '<%:Url.Action("Index", "Report", new { id = Model.GroupID})%>'" />
```

I am able to successfully change to the indicated page and the page's controller get's called. `Model.GroupID` is the value I need to submit the new form with.

**Q1**: How can I trigger the dropdown box to go to the desired selected index and then populate the textbox with the value from `Model.GroupID'?

**Index.aspx**

```
...
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "some" }))
{
      ....
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox.input, new { id = "textboxID", style = "width:" + Model.textBox.width + "px", maxlength = Model.textBox.maxLength })%>

      <input type="submit" name="button" value="Find Details" style="width: 180px" />
 }
```

I need to then submit the form, which will call my controller

**Controller.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report([Bind(Include = "textBox")]Report values)
{
    ....
}
```

**Q** is there a way to call the directly from the different view? I don't mind creating a seperate method in the controller either to avoid binding....

Answer (score 0):

for triggering a drop down list to select a specific item you can do like that:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupID, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["GroupsAvailable"], "Value", "Text", Model.GroupID))`

but you must also pass the `GroupsAvailable` by `ViewData` or inside your model.

you can pass it like that by `ViewData`

`IEnumerable<SelectListItem> availableGroups = db.Groups
        .Where(g => g.IsActive) // for example
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.GroupName
        });
        ViewData["GroupsAvailable"] = availableGroups.ToList();`

but over all you question it's not clear what do you want to achieve to answer your second question.